# Can I please create a canonical grouping question?

Tags: discussion

I have some resource material from ABRSM, Trinity Guildhall and UNISA than can answer all the grouping questions that are a recurring theme here.

I can ask and answer my own question and create a community wiki if need be.

Not just would be a tremendous resource for many musicians all over the world it will also reduce question bloat in regards to all these grouping questions which are all variants of the same question in essence.

Would like community feedback on how it would be best to do this.

Comment: I would definitely welcome something like this - thank you Neil. Simplest might be to look at the most common form of question and extend it to include all 3.

Comment: Let's see a couple of examples to help us make up minds.